# Will a 2017 MacBook Pro run the new visionOS SDK in Xcode and especially the Vision Pro emulator?

Tags: xcode, macos, virtual-reality

As the title says I want to learn to code apps for Vision Pro. But I don’t have a MacBook and the most I can afford right now is a used 2017 MacBook Pro with an i5 processor, 16gb RAM, and on board graphics.

I feel like this will run Xcode 15 fine, but won’t run vision pro simulator with it having on board graphics.

Comment: You need an Apple Silicon based Mac for the visionOS simulator. You can try it with latest Xcode 15 beta.

Answer (score 0):

I can‘t give you a direct answer but consider these points:

-The machine is reaching end of support for new OS installation if not at end of life, (check Apple Website compatibility for current and Sonoma OS compatibility) Yep it‘s likely getting security updates, but won‘t be compatible for an OS update for much longer.

- It‘s an Intel Mac and the likely-hood of Apple compiling the VisionOS simulator and tooling for Intel given both run natively on Apple Silicon i.e at a minimum M1 possibly M2 exclusively, is I would say minimal to non existent.

So keep your money in your pocket and save for a more modern machine.

Bear in mind what I‘ve expressed here is opinion, but is based onfacing the same dilemmas around iOS app dev.